# Jupyter notebook stopped running on AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I used to run this Jupyter notebook with no problems (using 8889 port) at all but since yesterday I have been having troubles accessing it. This is what happens when I ssh to my server on AWS (below). When I copy/paste this url in Safari I get this message: "Safari cannot open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection". SSH works fine though. Will appreciate help of this community as I'm new to AWS.

```
ssh [xxx]
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ cd mydir
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/mydir$ source myenv/bin/activate
(myenv) ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/mydir$ jupyter notebook
[I xxx NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I xxx NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu/mydir
[I xxx NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I xxx NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=XXX
[I xxx NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W xxx NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
[C xxx NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this to see what process is using that port

```
sudo netstat -tupln | grep 8888
```

Afterwards kill that process and try to start up notebook again.

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Comment: I use this port to run a Jupyter notebook locally.